# HTML5 Video Stops Immediately( works fine in firefox, opera)

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have an embedded video  in my web page.  Most of the videos works fine but  some of the videos  immediately stops at the beginning.  Those videos  work perfectly fine on  opera and  firefox.

It is like, I click play,  and immediately it stops. and reloads the video.

I have tried almost everything I can, still have no idea.

Do you think should I use a  video player library?

Has anyone ever come across this?

Comment: can you share an example showing a good and bad video?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal  I cut the first seconds of the video,  suddenly it started to play without a problem. Additionally it decreased  1 minute from the total time and 100mb.   I have no idea what was it.